# How to create a new MVC application on my dev server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a site on my dev server that is early enough in development that I'd like to start over in MVC 4. (The server is Windows 2012, FWIW).

The only MVC I've done at this point are tutorials that walk through creating an internet application project in Visual Studio 2012. As I've already got the site running in IIS on the dev server, I'd just like VS to create the project in the existing folder (e.g., C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\abc.com), but when I try that, it creates a `packages` folder and an `abc.com` folder containing the site code in the existing `abc.com` folder.

Perhaps I'm just used to opening an existing site via filesystem or FTP and I'm not used to web applications (vs. web projects), but I'm not getting how I can create my project and have the files sit in the appropriate folder.

Comment: What do you mean "create the project in the existing folder"? Why would your project be on the server? Typically just the deployment files (e.g. aspx and DLLs) are on the server. Develop locally -> publish to server. Maybe I misunderstand the question. [One-Click Publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx)

Comment: You don't want your Visual Studio project in the public web folder.  You want to develop in another folder (or, ideally, on another machine) and publish the result of that development to the IIS folder.  It sounds like you were doing this wrong in the first place, which has led to your current issue.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev/David: Well, yes. That's my question. But reading both your comments, I think I'm starting to understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project should not be in the "existing folder" (I'm guess the folder for the deployed website?). There should be no .cs files there. Just DLLs and your views (.cshtml, etc) and so on.

If you really need the project on the dev server (not sure why though), put it on a different drive, etc. Or better yet, develop and test locally. Then publish to dev and test. Then publish live.

To get your project "deployed", use the [Publish option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx) in Visual Studio (Right click the solution -> Publish... and configure as needed). This will copy over the necessary files for the website to run, but none of the solution/project files, etc.